# How do I parse the value of a field from the response HTML using karate

Tags: html, karate

I send a GET request ,then return date of html .I want to get the value="12345678qwert"

, what I should do with Karate

Answer (score 1):

Karate doesnt parse html. i suggest add another package that can parse html data. and use that then in your match statements. (This answer is in case i understood your question right...)